# How can I expose a git repo so that users on other machines can add it as a remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a git repo on an Ubuntu server. I would like users on MacOS workstations to be able to add this repo as a remote, and push files to it. How can I configure the git repo on the Ubuntu box to allow this?

Sorry if this is an elementary question, or doesn't make sense. I'm still finding my footing with git, and I'm not even sure what to Google to find the answer to this.

Comment: Google: `ssh`, `git init --bare`

Comment: Consider using gitolite3. This gives much more fine grained access control and should be available from your standard package sources.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. That led me to this link:

http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/

...which explains what a bare repository is, and why I should use one when setting up a shared repo.

This gets me going in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question. If you've found a solution, could you please answer it yourself?